# Isotropic vs Anisotropic Textures

Tags: terminology

I am reading the paper *Texture Synthesis over Arbitrary Manifold Surfaces* available [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/texture-synthesis-sig01/texture.pdf?q=illustrating-smooth-surfaces).

On page $3$ on the right sight of the page they refer to isotropic and anisotropic textures.
I am familiar with anistropic texture filtering, but not an actual texture itself called anisotropic.

Further they refer to an *n-way symmetric texture*, which I am not familiar with, and a google search did not yield any results.

I am guessing an *anisotropic* texture is a texture that accounts for different viewing directions (?) and perhaps an *n-way symmetric texture* is such a texture that accounts for $n$ different viewing directions?

If anyone could clarify these two terms that would be much appreciated. I realize this paper is from $2001$ so these terms might not still be in use.

Comment: A texture where structures have a specific directionality (e.g. Fig. 7 stripes). If you compute the power spectrum of such a texture, you will see that the energy is concentrated along specific directions.

Comment: @lightxbulb what is a texture spectrum?

Comment: These textures where used before anisotropic filtering appeared as a hardware feature, it's basically a hack to be make bilinear filtering more anisotropic.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density
An anisotropic texture has structures that are "elongated" along some direction(s).